# Android java EditText to int

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to store the input from the user in the EditText boxes and store them as a string so I can access it.

I used

```
               nameIn = name.toString();
               Log.i(null, nameIn);
```

(Think thats how you do it and it works fine)
but when I use the same code in my int, it won't work..
Now how do I write it so that it can get the users input and store it in my int variable?

This is my code:

```
        TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    TextView numberText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberText);

    EditText nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    EditText numberInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberInput);

    nameInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable name) {
        nameIn = name.toString();
        Log.i(null, nameIn);    
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });


    numberInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable number) {

            //this bit im stuck storing the inputted text to an int



        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt(String) function to convert your string to int

Answer (score 3):

Use `Integer.parseInt(yourString)` to get an integer value from a `String`.

More [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

In your case:

```
try {
    int myInt = Integer.parseInt(numberInput.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but somehow not working.. its giving me an error for getText()

Comment: `try {
       int myInt = Integer.parseInt(numberInput.getText().toString());
       Log.i("log",Integer.toString(myInt));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: What's the error? You're putting this after numberInput has been instantiated right? numberInput is not null?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you try to parse non number value. If your input contains spaces pr not a number characters - `Integer.parseInt()` method will fail and throw NumberFormatException.

To avoid this - add

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

attribute to your edittext in layout xml. With this attribute user wouldn't be able to enter any other than positive or negative number.

See details [here.](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Type)

After this you can use `Iteger.parseInt()` method safely, also I suggest to use `String.trim()` to remove any whitespace character in the beginning and the end of input if it contains so:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable number) {
    String numberStr = number.toString().trim();
    //check if your input is not empty
    if (numberStr.isEmpty()) return;
    try {
        //you should create numberIn int type variable like nameIn
        numberIn = Integer.parseInt(numberStr);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String nameIn;
int nameInt;
try {
  nameInt = Integer.parseInt(nameIn);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  Log.i("Log", "Not a number")
}
```